# What is React Native Permissions & how to use it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to use the React Native Permissions Library?
I have started learning it tell me the best practices using the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App permissions help support user privacy by protecting access to the following:

- Restricted data, such as system state and a user's contact information.
- Restricted actions, such as connecting to a paired device and recording audio.
  react-native-permissions
  A unified permissions API for React Native on iOS, Android and Windows.
  You can install it from terminal  by the following command

  $ npm install --save react-native-permissions

  ## --- or ---

  $ yarn add react-native-permissions

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#readme

Understanding permission flow
As permissions are not handled in the same way on iOS and Android, this library provides an abstraction over the two platforms' behaviors. (Check details here). 
Update Pod files for installing permission handler.
By default no permission handler is installed.
Update your **Podfile** by choosing the ones you want to check or request, then run pod install.

```
Example

    target 'YourAwesomeProject' do
    
      # …
    
      permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
    
      pod 'Permission-AppTrackingTransparency', :path => "#{permissions_path}/AppTrackingTransparency"
      pod 'Permission-BluetoothPeripheral', :path => "#{permissions_path}/BluetoothPeripheral"
      pod 'Permission-Calendars', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Calendars"
      pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
      pod 'Permission-Contacts', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Contacts"
    
    end
```

Then update your Info.plist with wanted permissions usage descriptions:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
        "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
        <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
        
          <!--  Keep only the permissions used in your app  -->
        
          <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
          <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
          <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
          <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
            <key>YOUR-PURPOSE-KEY</key>
           </dict>
        </dict>
        </plist>
```

**For Android**
Add all wanted permissions to your
app android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myawesomeapp">

  <!--  Keep only the permissions used in your app  -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" 
  />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" 
  />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

  <!-- … -->

</manifest>
```

And Then use it like below

```
 import {check, PERMISSIONS, RESULTS} from 'react-native-permissions';

check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS)
  .then((result) => {
    switch (result) {
      case RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE:
        console.log('This feature is not available (on this device / in 
        this context)');
        break;
      case RESULTS.DENIED:
        console.log('The permission has not been requested / is denied 
        but requestable');
        break;
      case RESULTS.LIMITED:
        console.log('The permission is limited: some actions are 
        possible');
        break;
      case RESULTS.GRANTED:
        console.log('The permission is granted');
        break;
      case RESULTS.BLOCKED:
        console.log('The permission is denied and not requestable 
        anymore');
        break;
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // …
  });
```

Comment: What is the best practice? Like creating a request function for each permission? Do we need to save the permission result given by user in async storage and retrieve it to conditionally check?

Comment: The best practice and the recommended way is to ask each permission separately and by the time when need to use it.
No we don't need to save the permission result given by the user as these are handeld  by operating system. we need to just check if these are allowed by user or not if not our app responed to user accordingly.